# Selecting and changing fields in QGIS graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I am trying to run a model that makes a selection from a refactored and name changed field, and changes the value of the selection.

Refactoring is easy, as is making the selection within the renamed field, but I have no idea how to change the selected values using the modeler.

I have tried field calculator, but its a different ballgame and a different syntax within the graphical modeler, so I'm not sure what to do.[image: model_example] [image]

Comment: I am managing an existing field that has been changed via Refactor. In this case I want to change all entries marked 'RURAL' to blank entries.  I've added a second picture showing what I would do outside of the graphical modeler.